# How to pass a list in asp.net-MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

With asp.net-4.0 I did this:

```
slideshow.aspx
<div class="wrapCarousel">  
    <div class="Carousel">  
       <% foreach(var image in Images) { %>
       <div class="placeImages">
        <img width="150px" height="150px" src="../Img/<%=image.TnImg%>" alt="<%=image.Name%>" />
        <div class="imageText">   
         <%=image.Name%>
        </div>
       </div>
       <% } %>
   </div>
```

And then Images was in the code behind like this
    slideshow.aspx.cs:

```
    public class Image
    {
        public string TnImg { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string RefPlace { get; set; }
        public string RefInfo { get; set; }
        public string RefInfoDynamic { get; set; }

        public Image(string TnImg, string Name, string City, string RefPlace, string RefInfo, string RefInfoDynamic)
        {
            this.TnImg = TnImg;
            this.Name = Name;
            this.City = City;
            this.RefPlace = RefPlace;
            this.RefInfo = RefInfo;
            this.RefInfoDynamic = RefInfoDynamic;
        }
    }

     Images.Add(new Image("", "",  "", "", "", "");
```

Now with asp.net-MVC2 I don't have any code behind so I can't access Images like before and some how instead need to pass it to the .aspx file.

How is this done?

Thanks
M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use a strongly typed view and pass the Model into the View from the controller.

You can find some details [here](http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnViews/BuildingAStronglyTypedView).

You would then use something like...

```
<% foreach(var image in Model.Images) { %>

   <div><%= image.Name %></div>

<% } %>
```

Your controller would look something like below, where you may get a list of images from some external source.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ImageViewModel imageViewModel = new ImageViewModel();
  imageViewModel.Images = _imageRepository.GetImages();

  return View ("Index", imageViewModel);    

}
```

In the above code you could just use the below to render the view

```
return View (imageViewModel);
```

I prefer to be explicit though with the call below, and specify the name of the view to render ( Even though it is the same name of the current controller action, I think it reads better)

```
return View ("Index", imageViewModel);
```

Comment: So in this case what is ImageViewModel() and should the foreach be like this "foreach(var image in Model.imageViewModel)" then?

Comment: If you strongly type your view as the ImageViewModel type, and that type had a property Images, you would access the data in your View with Model.Images.

Comment: `ImageViewModel` is a class you create that has the `Images` property. In the view, you then refer to the passed-in instance of the model class as `Model`.

Comment: Okay, I see and GetImages(); is the function that returns the images that I want to have on my index.aspx? The problem is that I'm not sure of how to create "ImageViewModel is a class you create that has the Images property" as a strongly type

Comment: ImageViewModel would just be a class definition, you could create a new folder called ViewModels and keep all your viewmodels in there. The images property would likely return a List<Image>. In this case the GetImages method would return a List<Image> for you to populate the property with.

Comment: Okay so I created that folder and added a file called ImageViewModel.cs then tried to create the class and so on but couldn't understand how it works. I'm sorry but could you please explain how ImageViewModel.cs should be written and also  where I should create and return the List<Image>. Would be really grateful for a complete example.